# How to create a new array that stores the users entered value and loops

Tags: arrays, loops, user-input

hi I need help creating a array that stores the users input as they enter the values. It should prompt the user to enter a number and that number is then store it into the new array, it should loop until the user has inputed the amount of numbers they want.

please help with any suggestions

Comment: Do you want it in pseduocode?

Comment: What language? Have you tried anything? This is a simple if statement that adds inputs into an array or vector depending on the language.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to fill an array of 10 strings in Java

```
    String[]temp= new String[10];
    for(int i =0;i< 10 ;i++){
        Scanner b = new Scanner(System.in); 
        temp[i] = b.next(); 
    }
```